# How to merge 2 database in xampp mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 databases, db and db1. I have new record from db1 and I want to put it in db. Now. I tried to import db1 however, it is not entering..
db and db1 has the same structures. However, they cannot be entered because a table already exists in one. But I need to merge the records together.

I have an sql file for db1. I just need to import records from it to db.

Comment: If the two databases are on the same server, then just simply use insert ... select ... to move data from one db to another using dbname.tablename format for tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to only merge the records if the 2 databases have the same structure.
Be careful about the identity column of the tables to prevent any conflicts.